# Multiple toggle-events with jquery on php-generated html

Tags: php, jquery

I know the title isn't the best, I didn't know how to put this in one sentence.
Anyway, I've got some php code creating pairs of links and corresponding boxes which should toggle, when I hit the link. Now I was wondering how you do this in jQuery "the right way".

Until now I gave every link the class `togglelink` and an ID `togglelink1`, `togglelink2` etc. The boxes then have the ID `togglebox1`... So I respond to `$(".togglelink").click()`, get the current ID, parse the number, add it to the box-ID and toggle the object.

This doensn't seem very straight foward as it's a task I'm sure is pretty common. Any suggestions on how I could improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your page is layed out you could use next to find the div to toggle. This way there would be no need for IDs.

```
$('.togglelink').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.togglebox').toggle();
});

<a href="#" class="togglelink">Link 1</a>
<div class="togglebox">Box 1</div>

<a href="#" class="togglelink">Link 2</a>
<div class="togglebox">Box 2</div>
```

Comment: In this case this really seems to be the best way. Thanks.

Comment: Imho this is generally not a really good solution for a toggler because it depends on your HTML structure, but since you generate the list with php it will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This actually is quite straight forward. One thing you may want to change is setting the IDs like this "togglelink-num" and "togglebox-num", you can then easily get the number with elem.id.split('-')[1]; instead of a pretty inconsistent parseInt(elem.id).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but it sound like you should check out jquery .toggle() [here.](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)